# Method of backing up Google Data Studio, Tag Manager, and Analytics configurations?

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, looker-studio

As my GDS usage grows, I get more and more concerned about being (as far as I can see) unable to get my report definitions into my source code repository. I can create backups within GDS itself, that clearly helps, but what happens if my account is corrupted and the reports get lost?

Also, with the Google-supplied arrangements I can see no way of listing what I actually changed in a particular delta.

It is possible to see the GDS reports on Google Drive, but they appear zero length.

And there seems no way of exporting my Google Tag Manager, or indeed Google Analytics, configuration, either. Google Sheets, which I use as a 'staging post' for GDS, *can* be backed up properly.

Has anyone found a way round this (other than loads of screen shots)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With GTM, there are two ways to back up:

- via the interface, you can download the complete container as as JSON file
- via the API, you can download individual tags, triggers and variables

There is currently no way to programmatically download the whole container. This is a frequent feature request in the GTM Google forum (or used to be before they moved to the new format), but it's hard to say when and if Google will respond to that.

With Google Analytics, you can back up some parts of the configuration (filters, segments and some more) via the API. Some things do not work with the API (e.g. channel definitions beyond the "default"), and there is no way to make a complete backup.

Data Studio, I don't know. The zero length things you see in Google Drive are more likely your Data Sources than your reports. That would be okay (the Data Source is the most relevant bit, since it contains all customizations like calculated fields), but you cannot download it or anything (for starter that would be a security issue, since the Data Source also contains authentication credentials for connected apps), so I frankly think you (or we all, rather) are a bit out of luck here.